# Setting pos_weight in weighted cross-entropy with mini-batch weights or global class weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I have data for a binary classification task which has the ratio of positive  to negative of 1:4. I'm using `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` with `pos_weight=4` after having read lots of questions on the weighted loss on Stack Overflow. However my loss is highly unstable, oscillating between 0.8 and 1.5 with each step.

I wanted to know how different would it be if I set `pos_weight` to a placeholder and fed it a variable of shape `[batch_size]` with the respective weights calculated from *that sample only*, i.e., if the sample has 3 positives and 18 negatives, the positives would be weighted with a factor of 6 instead of 4. So what happens to the learning process?

Comment: You could do that. But such an unstable loss is probably being caused by something else going wrong (your data is not formatted correctly and so on).

Comment: +1 to Nimitz14 comments. I would check basic things like learning rate, norm of gradients, variable initialization, etc. Also, stats.stackexchange.com is a better place for ML questions.